# Binary data from mongodb gets corrupted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose, socket.io

When I upload a photo it converts to base64 and then when I send to mongodb using Mongoose it saves as Binary. But when I call the same picture back from the database it returns as Buffer array. After converting to base64 it returns as a base64 string but completely different from the original base64. The new base64 is unable to be rendered in browser because it has been corrupted. 
Below are pictures of the different strings

This is the initial base64
[image]

This is the Buffer array 
[image]

This is the corrupted base64 after converting from the buffer array using Buffer.from(avatar).toString('base64'). 
Please note that I appended to it "data:image/png;base64," before rendering in the browser and it still did not render.
[image]

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: could you also post the relevant codes

Answer (score -1):

the best solution is convert to png or jpg file and upload only path and save image to folder.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it.
I converted from binary to utf8 instead of to base64.

There is a huge difference bewteen 
 Buffer.from(binary_data, 'binary').toString('utf8')

and

Buffer.from(binary_data, 'binary').toString('base64')